# Plotting a lambda with embedded if statement in Python using pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, lambda

I want to do something like this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
xpts = np.linspace(0, 100, 1000)
test = lambda x: 0.5 if x > 66 else 1.0
plt.plot(xpts, test(xpts))
```

but I get the error:

> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is
>   ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

On the other hand, I am able to do:

```
print(test(50), test(70))
```

> 1.0 0.5

Why is this happening and is there a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot convert an array to `bool` if it contains more than one element:

```
In [21]: bool(np.array([1]))
Out[21]: True

In [22]: bool(np.array([1, 2]))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-5ba97928842c> in <module>()
----> 1 bool(np.array([1, 2]))

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

You, probably, want to apply `test` function for each element in the array:

```
In [23]: plt.plot(xpts, [test(x) for x in xpts])
Out[23]: [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x7fa560efeeb8>]
```

You may also create vectorized version of your function and apply it to the array, without list comprehension:

```
In [24]: test_v = np.vectorize(test)

In [25]: plt.plot(xpts, test_v(xpts))
Out[25]: [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x7fa560f19080>]
```

Answer (score 3):

Python lists will not allow you to perform comparisons to a list.  So you can't for instance, do range(10) > 10.  Instead, you can convert the input to a numpy array and perform the range checking.  T

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
xpts = np.linspace(0, 100, 1000)
test = lambda x: (np.array(x) <= 66)*.5 + .5
print xpts, test(xpts)
plt.plot(xpts, test(xpts))
plt.show()
```